Moleculer micro service rooting not working in case of separate services rooting
when i try ti implement code like that it works:
gateway.service.ts
{
                path: "/api",
                whitelist: [ "**"],
                use: [],
                mergeParams: true,
                authentication: true,
                authorization: true,
                autoAliases: true,
                aliases: {
                    "login": "auth.login",
                },


                bodyParsers: {
                    json: {
                        strict: false,
                        limit: "1MB",
                    },
                    urlencoded: {
                        extended: true,
                        limit: "1MB",
                    },
                },

                
                mappingPolicy: "all", // Available values: "all", "restrict"

                // Enable/disable logging
                logging: true,
            },
 {
                path: "/controller",
                bodyParsers: {
                    json: false,
                    urlencoded: false
                },
                aliases: {
                    "POST /upload": {
                        params: {
                            file: { type: "file", required: true },
                            checkList: { type: "string", default:'' }
                        },
                        type: "multipart",
                        busboyConfig: {
                          limits: {
                            files: 3
                          }
                        },
                        action: "controller.post"
                      }
                },

                busboyConfig: {
                    
                    limits: {
                        files: 3
                    }
                },

                mappingPolicy: "restrict"
            }

but when i separte every rooting for the specific service it not works : like that:
gateway.service.ts
{
                path: "/api",
                whitelist: [ "**"],
                use: [],
                mergeParams: true,
                authentication: true,
                authorization: true,
                autoAliases: true,
                aliases: {
                    "login": "auth.login",
                },


                bodyParsers: {
                    json: {
                        strict: false,
                        limit: "1MB",
                    },
                    urlencoded: {
                        extended: true,
                        limit: "1MB",
                    },
                },

                
                mappingPolicy: "all", // Available values: "all", "restrict"

                // Enable/disable logging
                logging: true,
            },

controller.service.ts
// here it not works but i don't know why
settings:{
routes:[
{
                path: "/controller",
                bodyParsers: {
                    json: false,
                    urlencoded: false
                },
                aliases: {
                    "POST /upload": {
                        params: {
                            file: { type: "file", required: true },
                            checkList: { type: "string", default:'' }
                        },
                        type: "multipart",
                        busboyConfig: {
                          limits: {
                            files: 3
                          }
                        },
                        action: "controller.post"
                      }
                },

                busboyConfig: {
                    
                    limits: {
                        files: 3
                    }
                },

                mappingPolicy: "restrict"
            }
]
}

i tried to impelement rooting and aliases of every service in it x.service.ts file
it not works when i put every rooting settings in it file , it works only when i put all the settings in the gateway.service.ts file
